# Checking local variable while unit testing on a component in Angular gives error

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

Suppose there are 2 components : AppComponent and TestComponent. I am calling TestComponent using it's directive in the HTML template of AppComponent. Now TestComponent has an @Input() property ( let it be myTitle ).

I am doing unit testing for TestComponent only. For title, i am passing a random value in the test itself. Here is the code for the same :

app.component.html

```
<span><app-test [myTitle]="title"></app-test></span>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent{
    title = {name: 'hello-world'};
}
```

test.component.html

```
<p>test works!!{{myTitle.name}}</p>
<button (click)="onClick()">Click Please !!!</button>
```

test.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() myTitle;
    filter;
    constructor(){

    }

    ngOnInit():void{
        this.myTitle.name = "Hi!!";
    }
    onClick(){
       this.filter="GokuSSj3";
    }
}
```

test.component.spec.ts

```
describe('Test component',() =>{
    let temp;
    let component: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() =>{
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           declarations: [TestComponent],
           schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
       }) 
       .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(()=>{
        temp = {name: "Heloooo"};
       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
       component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should check First',()=>{
       component.myTitle = temp;
       console.log(component.myTitle.name);
       console.log(temp.name);

       fixture.detectChanges();

       console.log(component.myTitle.name);
       console.log(temp.name);
       expect(component.myTitle.name).toEqual(temp.name);
    });

    it('should check whether onClick is called on button click or not and also the value of filter',()=>{
       component.myTitle = temp;
       spyOn(component,'onClick');
       fixture.detectChanges();

       let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
       btn.triggerEventHandler('click',null);

       fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
          expect(component.onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
          expect(component.filter).toEqual("GokuSSj3");
    });
});
```

The second test case shows the error : Expected undefined to equal 'GokuSSj3'. Why is it so? Even though onClick has been called.

I am new to this community, so please help me improve the question if there are any fails.

Comment: I bet there should be `component.filter` instead of `component.fixture`

Comment: Yes. Apologies for negligence. Changes done. Thank you.

Comment: Again as commented on a similar question you have provided, testing that a button triggers the onClick event doesn’t make sense. You are basically testing the library or even the lower level HTML button. You can be sure that when you click a button it will trigger an onClick event. You don’t need to test it. You should be testing the behaviour of the code you produce. Not HTML components behaviour

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Then how do i get to fix the undefined error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have added spy on onClick function, it will never fire and update value of filter.

You need to remove that spy function and see the actual value change.

Change test as below:

```js
it('should check whether onClick is called on button click or not and also the value of filter', () => {
      component.myTitle = temp;
      fixture.detectChanges();

      let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
      btn.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.filter).toEqual("GokuSSj3");
      });
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Gaurav. But why it is not working with spyOn ? Is it because spyOn just intercepts function calls?

Comment: spyOn mock the event and bypass actual implementation

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/#_mocking_with_spies

Comment: If you are okay with your response then you should mark that response as answer to help other who are seeking for same kind of solution

Comment: Done. Is it fine now?

Comment: Also if that is not your question, means you cannot mark as answer. you can always upvote

Comment: Ok that being said, to upvote on question one needs to have greater than 15 rep, but no restrictions on answer?

Comment: Yes. there is no restrictions on answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211541/discussion-between-rahul-chowdhury-and-gourav-garg).

Comment: Hello, can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095430/callback-and-testing-highcharts