# Callback and Testing Highcharts

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, highcharts, karma-jasmine

I am currently using angular 9 with Highcharts.

`Link to the code :` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wdejxk

Some instructions for running on application-side / test-side :

1. **Test - side** : inside `angular.json` file on line number 18, change

   ```
       "main": "src/main.ts",
   ```

   to

   ```
       "main": "src/main-testing.ts",
   ```

and do a refresh of the browser.

2. **Application - side** : Change exactly the opposite of previous.

   ```
      "main": "src/main-testing.ts",
   ```

   to

   ```
      "main": "src/main.ts",
   ```

Here are a few issues i am stuck upon :

1. I have used **chart callback** to get the chart instance , but it is not working ( inside `hello.component.ts` ,
   line numbers 38 to 40 ). How should i call it and when does actually the callback happens in Highcharts ?
2. If suppose somehow i am able to assign the chart instance to chartCreated variable. Can i control the 
   chart now, like line numbers 60 to 62 ( if i **uncomment** that ), will it work ? Basically i wanted to 
   know the **`usefulness of updateFlag`** in Highcharts.
3. Unable to addSeries when ngOnChanges is called inside `hello.component.ts`
4. Inside the spec file  `hello.component.spec.ts`  i wanted to test the chart by putting a numeric data / adding a series 
   on my own , like i did when onClick() is called. But **`jasmine shows error`**

   ```
      TypeError : Cannot read series of undefined
      TypeError : Cannot read property 'addSeries' of undefined
   ```

   How to resolve these ?

**EDIT 1** : Implemented ngOnChanges and ngOnInit and removed most of the code from app.component.ts to hello.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    If you add the ngOnInit lifecycle hook, you will get values:

    1. export class AppComponent implements OnInit {.....


    2. ngOnInit(){
            this.chartCallback = (chart) => {
                this.chartCreated = chart;
                console.log('chart: ' + chart.chartHeight);         // shows 400
                console.log('this.chartCreated: ' + this.chartCreated.chartHeight); // shows 400
            }
          }

       addNewDataToChart(){
            this.updateFlag = false;
            this.chartCreated.addSeries({                     
            data: [3,4,2],                                         
            type: 'line'                                           
         });
            this.updateFlag = true;
       }

3. onClick(){
    if(this.clicked === false){
      this.chartCreated.series[0].data[0].update(4);
      this.clicked = true;
    } else {
      this.chartCreated.series[0].data[0].update(1);
      this.clicked = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello @user12307613, please check the latest edit of mine, i have also made some changes to the code taking into account your solution, but it did not work somehow. Can you please check again?

Comment: Hi @KL_KISNE_DEKHA_HAI, i have updated the Stackblitz for you to be able to add a new entry into the chart. 

There is now a function called "addNewDataToChart()" which takes responsibility of that: 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qpkpbu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Hello @gsa.interactive , thank you for doing the respective changes. It works. Can you tell me why it did not work with OnChanges lifecycle hook? And also about why the callback function worked inside ngOnInit and not when i placed it inside constructor ?

Comment: Also ,when to use updateFlag ? like in your function called "addNewDataToChart()" even if i remove it still works...

Comment: Hi @KL_KISNE_DEKHA_HAI,

Angular has a special process how and when components are initialized. This is a nice read about that topic.

Will help you understand it: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/lifecycle-hooks/

Comment: Hello @gsa.interactive , here is a follow up question regarding some issues , i am still stuck with :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140215/highcharts-instance-created-in-which-angular-life-cycle-hook. Please see to it.

Answer (score 1):

As per @gsa.interactive suggestion , following test cases worked :

```
  it('should check for changes in the data of the series in charts ',()=>{
      component.chartCreated.series[0].data[0].update(5);
      //console.log(component.chartCreated);
      expect(component.chartCreated.series[0].yData).toEqual([5,2,3]);
  });

  it('should check for changes in the series in charts ',()=>{
    component.chartCreated.addSeries({
        data: [3,4,2],
        type: 'line'
    });

    //console.log(component.chartCreated);
    expect(component.chartCreated.series.length).toBe(2);
    expect(component.chartCreated.series[1].yData).toEqual([3,4,2]);
  });
```